# AWS ElasticSearch Client SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-sdk, amazon-elasticsearch

Is there any AWS ElasticSearch Client SDK for Java, which signs the requests with AWS credentials? I saw [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch), but I guess its for managing AWS Elasticsearch Service.

Comment: What client language are you using?

Comment: I am using Java

Answer (score 0):

You can create AWS client for Elasticsearch in the following way:

```
AwsClientBuilder.withCredentials(AWSCredentialsProvider) for example: AWSElasticsearchClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();
```

How I do this is by first creating AWSBasicSessionCredential instance by providing awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, and sessionToken information and then passing this instance in the above code to build the client instance. However, I do this for test programming the clients. Its not advised to create a client this way though. For example, one secure way would be using federated identification to generate a temporary security token and then use that to assume a role through AWS' AssumeRoleRequest, receive its response in the form of AssumeRoleResult and then retrieve credential information from the assumeRoleResult response received above. Use this credential information in generating AWSCredential.

[Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticsearch/AWSElasticsearchClient.html) of generating AWS Elasticsearch client.

Comment: The client you suggested is used for Amazon Elasticsearch configuration. I am looking for something like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html) but with signed requests